# splitList Function in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

In my homework, there is a question, I copied below.

Write a function splitList that gives all the ways to split a list of at least two elements in two non-empty parts. The type declaration is:

```
splitList :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
```

The call `splitList [1..4]` should give:

```
Prelude> splitList [1..4]
[([1],[2,3,4]),([1,2],[3,4]),([1,2,3],[4])]
```

And here is the code I wrote:

```
splitList :: Eq a=> [a]->[([a],[a])]
splitList []=[([],[])]
splitList (x:xs) = [([x],xs)]++[(splitList xs)]
```

But it gives an error: `` Couldn't match expected type `([a], [a])' with actual type `[([a], [a])]' ``

```
splitList (x:xs) = [([x],xs)]++[(splitList xs)]
```

I made bold where the error highlighted.

Comment: Since `splitList xs` will return a value of type `[([a], [a])]` you can not use `[(splitList)]` since then  you wrap it in another list, and thus you construct a value of type `[[([a], [a])]]`.

Comment: `[(splitList xs)]` should be simply `splitList xs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you wrap the `splitList xs` in another list, and thus you construct a value of type `[[([a], [a])]]`. You thus should replace this with:

```
splitList :: Eq a => [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splitList [] = [([],[])]
splitList (x:xs) = [([x],xs)] ++ splitList xs
```

or more elegant:

```
splitList :: Eq a => [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splitList [] = [([],[])]
splitList (x:xs) = ([x],xs) : splitList xs
```

This is however not sufficient, you will need to prepend the first item of the 2-tuples of `splitList` with `x` in. You can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=map) for this. This will thus look like:

```
splitList :: Eq a => [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splitList [] = [([],[])]
splitList (x:xs) = ([x],xs) : map … (splitList xs)
```

where `…` is still something you need to fill in yourself.

Note that your function here will also return a 2-tuple where the *second* list is empty. Based on the expected output, that is not the what you intend to do. You can define an extra clause like:

```
splitList :: Eq a => [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splitList [] = []
splitList x@[_] = [([], x)]
splitList (x:xs) = ([x],xs) : map … (splitList xs)
```

where `…` is still something you need to fill in yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried ` (\(y,ys)<-([x:y],ys)) ` for the `...` part and some other things before but all was wrong so I gave up and asked my friend and the answer was `(\(y,ys)->(x:y,ys)) ` , so I am feeling awkward because I did think right but I gave up so early :D. So thank you sooo much.